# php Query a database

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I queried an sql server database and got a recordset with 5 rows. I then looped through the recordset doing my output. All was fine when i used:

```
<?= $row.['Photo'] ?>
```

to output the value.

When I tried to ask if the value from the database was null, I ran into problems. PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion.

```
if ($row.['Photo'] == "" || $row.['Photo'] == null){
    echo $row.['Photo'];
else{
    //something else;
}
```

This was so that if no photo was indicated in the record, I could display something else.

I have researched this and was unable to find the answer. I tried

```
$photo = strval($row.['Photo']);
$photo = implode("",$row.['Photo']);
```

Here is my query:

```
$serverName = "IT-NEWITWEB-D\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"eVENTS", "UID"=>"uSER", "PWD"=>"P@\$\$" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT tblEvents.EventID, tblEvents.Photo, tblEvents.title, tblLocation.Date, tblLocation.Location, tblEvents.unlist, tblEvents.description, tblEvents.Par_num FROM tblLocation INNER JOIN tblEvents ON tblLocation.Event_ID = tblEvents.EventID GROUP BY tblEvents.EventID, tblEvents.Photo, tblEvents.title, tblLocation.Date, tblLocation.Location, tblEvents.unlist, tblEvents.description, tblEvents.Par_num HAVING (((tblEvents.unlist)>getdate()) AND ((tblEvents.Par_num)=261));";
//$params = array();

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
 //if photo is empty, display date instead.
 }
```

Comment: `<?= $row.['Photo'] ?>` gave you something??

Comment: Yes. The value of the field in that row of the returned recordset.

Comment: That seems unlikely. https://3v4l.org/k1rND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're doing wrong, use this `$row['Phone'];` instead of `$row.[];`

getting property of Object!

Comment: you are right. I am doing it wrong. I removed the . and all was good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that PHP interprets that you are trying to concatenate $row with something else. Try removing the dots "$row.['Phone']".

Another thing that I noticed is that, in your example, you are printing only when the value is empty or null. To do the opposite you should do:

```
if ($row['Photo'] != "" && $row['Photo'] != null){
    echo $row['Photo'];
else{
    //something else;
}
```

Or

```
if (is_array($row) && !empty($row['Photo'])) {
    echo $row['Photo'];
else{
    //something else;
}
```